# Are questions on the historical inauguration of some "utilities" or "methods" on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, off-topic, on-topic

I'd like to ask if question about the introduction of utilities or methods to help Muslims in some acts of worship.

For example: a Calendar or calculation method to determine the new moon.

Are questions like these on-topic?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. Can you elaborate on your examples?

Comment: @goldPseudo well i think a calendar or methods to calculate the moon phases have been developped in the golden ages of islamic caliphats but i'd like to know when scholars introduced or accepted them as a utillity for declaring or calculating important dates like 1st day of Ramadan ...

Comment: You can check here for feasibility:  [How to calculate the moon phase](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11273/how-to-calculate-the-moon-phase)

Comment: Astronomical calculations made by various sources you can find on internet: https://stardate.org/nightsky/moon

Question is are they reliable?

Comment: @nim thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a question which is on similar topic: [Global Islamic Calendar](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/global-islamic-calendar)

IMHO If this question has place in this site yours may have a place also.

Comment: Sounds good I'll check that!